# JavaFX differentiate between scrolling up and scolling down in setOnScroll event

Tags: javafx, mouseevent

Currently working on a puzzle game in JavaFX which displays pieces to play on screen and when you scroll over them, they rotate. This works fine but right now they only rotate in one direction, how do I find out whether the mouse is scrolling up or down?

Comment: http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/javafx/scene/input/ScrollEvent.html#getDeltaY--